# Salesforce Release Update - "Enforce Data Access in Flow Merge Fields"

Tags: visual-workflow, summer-21, release-update

I wanted to reach out to ask a few questions about this release update: [Enforce Data Access in Flow Merge Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_release_update_enforce_data_access.htm&type=5&release=228)

1. Will this impact Process Builders as well?
2. I know we can update the Running User on certain Flows like screenflows. What about record triggered flows?

The timeframe to do a "Test Run" on this has elapsed, and we are trying to prepare for what might happen.

Curious to see how the community at large is testing/approaching this with the summer 21 release around the corner. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reached out to the product team about this.

From a purely technical standpoint, this change applies to all flows.

However, practically, it only has an impact on Flows that run in the user context such as screen flows and autolaunched flows that run from clicking on a button.

If a flow runs in system context, like process builder, scheduled flows, record-change triggered flows, and non-UI autolaunched flows ignore  object and field security and sharing. They did warn that there may be a few corner case objects.